# How to handle progress indicator upon canceling google sign-in dialog?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

When user clicks on `Google Sign in` button, the progress indicator is set to true and the app shows dialog to select user accounts from. If user clicks outside of the dialog or system back button, the progress indicator keeps showing.

Where and how do I set the `_isLoading = false` so that the progress indicator goes away ?

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(_isLoading ? 20.0 : 0.0),
              width: 75,
              height: 75,
              child: _isLoading
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : IconButton(
                      icon: Image.asset('assets/google.png'),
                      onPressed: () => _handleGoogleSignIn()),
            )
```

...

```
Future<Null> _handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    LoginUtils().handleGoogleSignIn().then((firebaseUser) {
      _postSignInAction(firebaseUser);
    }).catchError((exception) {
      _handleLoginException(exception);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you disable it by clicking outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what exactly `LoginUtils().handleGoogleSignIn()` does. Given that it is a Future, if what it does is display the dialog to select the Google account, it should complete as soon as the dialog is dismissed. I would expect it to complete successfully, with `firebaseUser` being null - this is the default behavior when popping routes by pressing back as well.

You should therefore simply have to add the following:

```
if (firebaseUser == null) {
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

If however that Future does not complete at all when the dialog is dismissed, then that's the problem you need to solve.